# Laptop - is it safe when using force shutdown (deep shutdown)

Tags: windows, laptop, windows-11, shutdown, asus-laptop

My asus laptop (FA507RC) is facing the issue that battery drained even i did a completely shutdown.
I found a solution here: [solution](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/battery-is-draining-after-shutting-down-the-laptop/5132887d-6111-446c-9dea-b36d1961d0a3) (hold power button after the laptop shutdown)

But i'm not sure this method is safe for my hardware/software or not. Please help to answer my question. Thank you

EDIT:

Fast startup is disabled
[image: fast startup]

Comment: If your laptop implements this feature, then it is safe to use. But this does not address the root cause.

Comment: It sounds safe, make sure you unplug every from the laptop, even connecting a USB hub might run the battery down

Answer (score 3):

According to this [website](https://www.isumsoft.com/windows-10/2-ways-to-perform-a-full-shutdown.html), you can also completely shut down the PC with these two options:

- Hold down the Shift key while pressing "Shutdown".
- type `shutdown /s /f /t 0` in the terminal.
  You can open the terminal by pressing the Windows key and then typing `cmd`.

For a better user experience, you could create a shortcut that automatically executes this command.